# I cannot trace more than 1 sphere by ray tracing algorithm

Tags: c++, graphics

in the code below, I want to draw all these 3 spheres(sphere, sphere1, sphere2 in "s" vector) by ray tracing algorithm. If I draw 1 sphere, it gives a good result but from 2 to n, image distorts.

I cannot catch my fault in this code. Could you please help me? How can I see three of the spheres?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Vec{
    double x,y,z;
    Vec(double x, double y, double z): x(x), y(y), z(z){}

    Vec operator + (const Vec& v) const {
        return Vec(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z); 
    }

    Vec operator - (const Vec& v) const { 
        return Vec(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z); 
    }

    Vec operator * (double d) const {
         return Vec(x*d, y*d, z*d); 
    } 

    Vec operator / (double d) const { 
        return Vec(x/d, y/d, z/d); 
    }

    Vec normalize() const {
        double norm = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        return Vec(x/norm,y/norm,z/norm);
    }
};

inline double dot(const Vec& u, const Vec& v) {
  return (u.x*v.x + u.y*v.y + u.z*v.z);
}

struct Ray{
    Vec origin, direction;
    Ray(const Vec& origin, const Vec& direction): origin(origin), direction(direction){}
};



struct Sphere{
    Vec center;
    double radius;
    Sphere(const Vec& center, double radius): center(center), radius(radius){}

    Vec getNormal(const Vec& point) const { return (point - center) / radius; } // Küre üzerindeki normal

    bool intersect(const Ray& ray, double &t) const { // t = parameter
    const Vec ori = ray.origin; //e 
    const Vec dir = ray.direction; //d
    const Vec origintocenter = ori - center; // e-c
    const double b = 2 * dot(origintocenter, dir); 
    const double c = dot(origintocenter, origintocenter) - radius*radius;
    const double a = dot(dir, dir);
    double delta = b*b - 4 * a * c;
    if (delta < 0) return false;
    delta = sqrt(delta);
    const double t0 = (-b - delta)/(2*a);
    const double t1 = (-b + delta)/(2*a);
    t = (t0 < t1) ? t0 : t1;
    return true;
  }
};

void range255(Vec& col) {
  col.x = (col.x > 255) ? 255 : (col.x < 0) ? 0 : col.x;
  col.y = (col.y > 255) ? 255 : (col.y < 0) ? 0 : col.y;
  col.z = (col.z > 255) ? 255 : (col.z < 0) ? 0 : col.z;
}

int main(){
    //image size
    const int width = 1000;
    const int height = 1000;

    //colors
    const Vec white(255, 255, 255);
    const Vec black(0, 0, 0);
    const Vec red(255, 0, 0);
    const Vec green(0,255,0);
    const Vec blue(0,0,255);

    const Sphere sphere(Vec(width*0.8, height*0.2, 30), 50);
    const Sphere sphere1(Vec(width*0.5, height*0.5, 30), 50);
    const Sphere sphere2(Vec(width*0.8, height*0.8, 30), 50);
    const Sphere light(Vec(0, 0, 0), 1);

    vector<Sphere> s;
    s.push_back(sphere);
    s.push_back(sphere1);
    s.push_back(sphere2);
    ofstream out("out.ppm");
    out << "P3\n" << width << ' ' << height << ' ' << "255\n";

    Vec pixelColor(black);

    double t;

    for(int y=0; y<height; ++y){
        for(int x=0; x<width; ++x){
            pixelColor = black;
            const Ray ray(Vec(x,y,0), Vec(0,0,1)); // z'den xy düzlemine gönderiyor
            for(int a=0; a<s.size(); ++a){
                if (s[a].intersect(ray, t)) {

                    const Vec p = ray.origin + ray.direction*t;
                    const Vec n = s[a].getNormal(p); //normal
                    const Vec l = light.center - p; // light condition
                    const double dt = dot(l.normalize(), n.normalize());

                    pixelColor = (red + white*dt) * 0.5;
                    range255(pixelColor);

            }

            out << (int)pixelColor.x << ' ' << (int)pixelColor.y << ' ' << (int)pixelColor.z << '\n';

            }
        } 
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing non-essential parts of your code until you have a working foundation, then add parts back in one at a time.  For example, what if you only render the second sphere, or the third?  What if you remove all lighting/normals and just test that intersection is working?  What if you output a warning or set a breakpoint when a color is negative prior to clamping?  What if you remove all raytracing and just output the ray direction as a color at each pixel to check your calculations?  This is the kind of approach to debugging that you should make common practice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anywhere in your code any check which sphere is closer. If your ray intersects multiple spheres, it should return the sphere, and the corresponding `t` value for the closest one.

Also, your code is defective if `t0` or `t1` or both are negative, i.e. the sphere is behind the viewer.

If I was you, I would just return `std::optional<double>` from the `Sphere::intersect(const Ray&)` and compare the result with `t` obtained from previous spheres that I tried to intersect. Only at the very end, when the closest sphere is known I would start shading (i.e. computing lighting and color).